# Formula that incorporates "xlUp" or dynamic range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data that comes in "blocks", that I need to `SUM()`.  However, the block sizes aren't the same, so I find myself manually adjusting the formula to fit the ranges.

Sample data:
[image]

```
Chicago         10
Denver          20
Anchorage       22

Denver          122
Gotham          23
Sky City        22
New Jack City   2

Sacramento      92

Memphis         1
Miami           22
Mordor          3
```

<sub>(Note: [I can't paste data here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320162), prompts me for image.)</sub>

The idea is to have a formula in column C that sums the data above.  So `C3` (or `C4`, whatever works) would sum `B1:B3`.  `C8` would sum `B5:B8`, etc.

I can do this with a UDF, no problem.

However, I'm curious if there's a formula I can use.  I've started with `SUMIF()` but get stuck almost immediately, as unfortunately my formula skills break down when trying to do something that incorporates an `IF()` within `SUM()`.  (My thoughts are the formula would need `AGGREGATE()` and `IF()` within `SUM()` ...like, `=SUM(IF(AGGREGATE(A1...` and I'm stuck...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in C2 and copy down:

```
=IF(A3="",SUM($B$1:B2)-SUM($C$1:C1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: !! That's so clever.  I didn't think to simply subtract from the values above the formula.  This is most excellent Scott, cheers! :D

Comment: (PS: Totally unrelated - can you copy from Excel and paste the data in to a post/question? Or is that issue just me?)

Comment: insert as java code snippet (the button that looks like `<>`) then remove the java script lines.